# Are formal languages/systems as general as bounded, clear axioms and finding consequences?

Tags: reference-request, frege, formalisation

I’ve tried searching PhilPapers for holistic accounts of formal/languages/systems and I’m not very successful, the best I’ve found being https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jafpos1956/12/1/12_1_15/_pdf/-char/en

I’m trying to understand the broadest concept all formal languages fall under, if that’s possible, and the big deal ascribed to formal languages as a whole.

But too broad and I can’t distinguish these concepts from natural language.

I’m only picking out axioms and  their consequences as the title says because other properties like alphabets and well formed formulae seem implicit and common to ALL uses of language.

And axioms and finding consequences, while part of natural languages, are not representative of all uses of language.

Can I hold such a general concept? Where this differs from the paper is apparently Frege also identified some “principles of thought” (bottom half of pg 21, top 22) to be encoded into the formal syntax so as to be revealed solely by looking at the syntax.

But I can only know those principles and that syntax by studying Frege’s work. No symbols have objective meaning (in Searle’s sense). By using our language facilities we identify symbols with meaning and use. So I’m back to being told rules following consequences. One of the most basic and instinctual aspects of language.

Since logical and mathematical pluralism don’t seem absurd to me, I feel formal languages a la Frege kind of just abstract the ambiguity one level higher: removed from the proofs but at the level of which syntax to even follow. Almost like now I have to learn a new language to operate under different principles of thought. Which seems like a trade off to natural language where there is one language and more ambiguity.

Am I too off base for this to be a good question, is it okay to have such a conception, is there resource I can read that’s a bit more in-depth than the paper I linked but doesn’t require a degree?

Comment: Its not completely clear what you're asking, but it seems like you would like an introduction to formal languages, there are many such textbooks out there.  The big deal about (some) formal languages is that we can guarantee that they are unambiguous, complete, sound, etc... properties that our natural language certainly does not have

Comment: @Papuseme I’ve heard Tim Maudlin say the idea of incompleteness is not something we had no idea of pre-formal language (heavily paraphrasing here but that’s how I took it — that in general, if you don’t know if a system is consistent you can’t use it to say it is). It didn’t take formal languages to know these concepts. That (proving and consistency) is one part of formal languages *and* natural language. I’m asking if there really is nothing truly distinct from natural languages other than where it specifically focuses (soundness,  completeness, axioms, etc)

Comment: But mostly axioms and consequences because soundness and completeness, etc are not feature of all formal languages.

Comment: well sure, we had an idea of what set theory was before ZFC, etc, and some versions of it led directly into contradiction. We had an idea of what continuity was prior to topology, distance prior to metrics, etc..... and yet philosophers, mathematicians, etc take into account formalizations when discussing them. Can you think of why?

Comment: @Papuseme thank you. Why they take into account formalizations? I think a quote from the paper (Frege) can answer "the mathematician rests content if every transition to a fresh judgment is self-evidently correct, without enquiring into the nature of this self-evidence..." pg 20. And formal languages provide that. But if these pre-formal concepts exist, why cant we fully express them non-formally too? Or has every time we've tried to it goes the russell's paradox route (self-contradicts or similar)? So formal languages do what nat languages can't even though pre-concepts exist?

Comment: It would be easiest if you read papers with formalizations- look at papers discussing the proper logic of modality, the proper set theory, etc... Then it will become clear why we discuss formalizations.